# Wordpress - CSS3 Animation not working on Firefox, but working on Chrome/Edge

Tags: html, wordpress, css, firefox

I'm having a strange problem with a custom rollover image I've made on Firefox. My site is using WP4.9.1.
I built my rollover image using some base code obtained online in JSfiddle. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ibbykhan/bgomu806/).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500);
figure.snip1206 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 310px;
  max-height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

figure.snip1206 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1206 img {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.snip1206:after {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.75;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg) scaleX(0);
  transform: skew(0deg) scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

figure.snip1206 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1206 h2,
figure.snip1206 p {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

figure.snip1206 h2 {
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure.snip1206 p {
  padding: 0 50px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

figure.snip1206 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1206:hover:after,
figure.snip1206.hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg) scaleX(1);
  transform: skew(0deg) scaleX(1);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

figure.snip1206:hover figcaption h2,
figure.snip1206.hover figcaption h2,
figure.snip1206:hover figcaption p,
figure.snip1206.hover figcaption p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

figure.snip1206:hover figcaption h2,
figure.snip1206.hover figcaption h2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

figure.snip1206:hover figcaption p,
figure.snip1206.hover figcaption p {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

figure.snip1206 .line-right,
figure.snip1206 .line-left {
  max-height: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width .75s; /* Safari */
  transition: width .75s;
  -moz-transition: width .75s;
  -o-transition: width .75s;
}

figure.snip1206 .line-right { right: 70%; }

figure.snip1206 .line-left { left: 70%; }

figure.snip1206:hover .line-right,
figure.snip1206:hover .line-left {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="snip1206">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample74.jpg" alt="sample74" />
  <figcaption>
    <span class="line-left"></span>
    <h2>Order</h2><span class="line-right"></span>
    <p>
      something
    </p>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>
```

When I add my code to my page in WP (I'm using SiteOrigin Page Builder with WP's Custom HTML widget) and add the CSS to my child theme CSS, the line animation doesn't work correctly. I tested this on Chrome and Edge and they both showed correctly. Anyone have an idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You don't have `-moz-` in all css rules where you have other vendor prefixes defined?

Comment: It appears to work in the new version of FF (Quantum).

Comment: @ProEvilz: By default I don't include `-moz-` to any of my stylesheets but I did to test if there was some compatibility issue for a reason I wasn't able to determine. It wasn't working either way. Scratching my head here.